# Disable vim-surround in a netrw buffer

Tags: key-bindings, netrw, plugin-vim-surround

Is there a way to disable a plugin (or a set of keymaps) on a specific filetype? `vim-surround` causes a delay in `netrw` when pressing `d` to create a new directory.

I'm thinking that this might be possible with an auto command that looks something like this:

`autocmd Filetype netrw ...something...`

There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/issues/98).

Comment: you can just delete the mapping (or comment it out)

Comment: I need the mapping in every other buffer, so commenting it out completely isn't really an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The surround plugin defines global mappings. Unfortunately, you can only *override* those with buffer-local ones, but not `:unmap` them only in the buffer. Temporarily disabling and re-defining the global surround mappings would be possible, but is cumbersome.

I think the best solution would be patching the netrw plugin to add the `<nowait>` argument to the `d` mapping (and all other buffer-local plugin mappings). This would fix the timeout issue, and you probably don't need to invoke the other (surround et al.) mappings on a netrw buffer, anyway.
Unfortunately, netrw's `d` mapping invokes a script-local function (`:call <SID>NetrwMakeDir("")`), so it's difficult to redefine the mapping with an `:autocmd FileType netrw`; you'd need the `<SID>` of netrw. So please suggest that enhancement to netrw's author, Chip Campbell; you'll find his address in the script header.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this makes sense. I've already sent an email to the author, hopefully this can be implemented soon.